# How to change height of an element of recycler view dynamically?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-recyclerview

I want to create animation just like this in android

https://joshwcomeau.github.io/react-flip-move/examples/#/shuffle?_k=smcdfi

so i want to change height along with scale down animation to delete an entry.

Comment: check this https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators

Comment: actually i want the elements below the element to be deleted to move up as deletion occurs. but in above link it first delete the entries and apply animation and then move below elements up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using ViewGroup.LayoutParams class

```
private void setDimensions(View view, int width, int height){
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = width;
    params.height = height;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

That would simplify your code significantly, because then you can just call this method for every single of your buttons, with proper values for width and height.

```
setDimensions(button, height/7, height/10);
setDimensions(button2, height/7, height/10);
setDimensions(button3, height/7, height/10);
```